# java.util.Queue that silently discards null elements

Tags: java

I'm looking for a [`java.util.Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementation or factory method that provides me with a `Queue` that silently discards `null` elements.

[`java.util.LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is not a solution, because it allows to *queue* `null` elements and to *unqueue* `null` elements (... the `Queue` shall *forward-unqueue* until it is either empty or has a `non`-null element on head position).
[`java.util.ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is not a solution, because it throws `NullPointerException` when trying to add a `null` element.

It shall be possible to construct such a `Queue` with an existing `Queue` (with that existing `Queue` possibly containing `null` elements which get removed by the newly constructed `Queue` upon operations).

Is there already a robust solution out there?

Comment: what about silently not adding null elements to the queue?

Comment: Just subclass another queue class and toss out null elements when added.

Comment: @HotLicks The `Queue` or factory method I am looking for shall allow "construction from another `Queue`". As that other queue may contain `null` elements, tossing out `null` elements only during *queue* (e.g. "add") operations doesn't fullfil the `Queue`'s contract. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

While I realise this doesn't directly answer your question, this answer should apply if you can't find an implementation and decide to make your own class.

I would discourage subclassing as suggested by 'Hot Licks' on account of the subclass not being true to the superclass's intended implementation and use (e.g. super could rely on being able to add null elements, and thus this breaks it). Furthermore, you break the Is-A principle by changing major implementation details.

I suggest you use composition, where you make the appropriate methods available through your own methods, which may change behaviour where necessary.

Read more in [Chapter 16](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&dq=composition%20effective%20java&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rCIkUbqGKoiM4ATjqoGoBg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=composition%20effective%20java&f=false) of Effective Java.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to have to create an entirely new subclass, you can just over-ride the methods you need to when you create your instance.

Here is an example:

```
final ArrayDeque<String> nonNullDeque = new ArrayDeque<String>() {
    @Override
    public void addFirst(final String s) {
        if (s != null) { super.addFirst(s); }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final String s) {
        return s != null && super.add(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void addLast(final String s) {
        if (s != null) { super.addLast(s); }
    }
};
```

This is the entire reason you have the ability to over-ride methods with your own behavior, the internal workings of the super class should be a black box, your contract with it is to accept the parameters and return the results that its interface supports, not to support its internal workings.

Personally I would go one step further instead of checking for the nulls and use JSR=305 `@Nonnull` annotation using the [Google findbugs library](http://code.google.com/p/findbugs-tutorials/). Not only will the annotation catch the `null` before your code gets a chance to, it implicitly documents what your intention is.

```
public void addFirst(@Nonnull final String s) {
    if (s != null) { super.addFirst(s); }
}
```

The Maven dependency is in Central Repo so that makes it painless to add to your project.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```